# Compiler warning: suggest parentheses around arithmetic in operand of '|'

Tags: c++, gcc

I have gone through all other similar issues, and yet I cannot understand why I am getting this error :

```
warning: suggest parentheses around arithmetic in operand of '|' [-Wparentheses]
 &((~((PERIPHS_IO_MUX_FUNC)<<(PERIPHS_IO_MUX_FUNC_S))))  \
```

I am using xtensa-gcc. Following is the code (from ESP8266 SDK) :

```
#define PIN_FUNC_SELECT(PIN_NAME, FUNC)  do { \
       WRITE_PERI_REG(PIN_NAME,   \
       (READ_PERI_REG(PIN_NAME)) \
            &((~((PERIPHS_IO_MUX_FUNC)<<(PERIPHS_IO_MUX_FUNC_S))))  \
            |((((FUNC&BIT2)<<(2))|(FUNC&0x3))<<(PERIPHS_IO_MUX_FUNC_S)) );  \
} while (0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "&" and "|" leading on the last two lines both are at the same level of parentheses.  The compiler is warning you that there can be some confusion by developers regarding precedence.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. But `&` is hardly "arithmetic", is it? Misleading message.

Comment: Depends on your definition of arithmetic. I use bitwise operators for arithmetic purposes when it makes sense. In any event, the message does say which operator is dangerous, so it's hardly misleading.